# How to ignore duplicates in recordset of Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Say I have a result set with these values:

orderID typeofSale

A1 Sell

A1 Buy

B1 Sell

C1 Sell

The total number of orders here is 3, as A1 got divided. How can this be calculated in Crystal?

I tried looping through the orders with WhileReadingRecords; and maintaining the order ids read in an array, and then checking of the order id had already been read, thus not double counting. However, Crystal has an array limitation of 1000 records only....

I've been struggling with this. For some reason, the prev report creator wants this value in the report header, making it all the more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DistinctCount`

In a formula you would do:

`DistinctCount({Table.Yourfield})`

Or from the menu `Insert` > `Summary` then choose the field you want summarize and select `Distinct Count` from the **Calculate this summary** drop down.

Comment: Hey Thanks Barry, though this is not what I was looking for. I suppose I should expand on my question:

Columns: OrderID Venue Side

Sample data: 

A1 x 1
A1 y 1
A1 z 1
B1 x 1
C1 y 2
C2 z 2

So the count of all orders with side = 1 would be 1. 

I solved this by using WhileReadingRecords; to maintain the order ids id already traversed and printed out the count in a WhilePrintingRecords;

I did run into a problem with arrays not being able to store more than 1000 elements, but bypased that by only ever keeping track of the last orderID read....

Comment: @habbu - So all you need to do is add a group for each OrderId and then do a distinct count of the sides.  I'm not really sure I follow what you are trying to achieve. But I guess you have it sorted now.